# Jenkins job dsl configure block with "plugin="

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to add new plugin via configure block to my jenkins jobs.

What I neeed is:

```
<jenkins.plugins.mattermost.MattermostNotifier plugin="mattermost@2.7.1">
```

What I get is:

```
 <jenkins.plugins.mattermost.MattermostNotifier>
```

My groovy script:

```
 job('newjob') {
        publishers {        
            if (!name.startsWith('_review')) {
                configure { project -> 
                    project / publishers / 'jenkins.plugins.mattermost.MattermostNotifier' << 'mattermost' {

                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I add this

```
plugin=mattermost@2.7.1
```

to the XML block?

Comment: Why do you need to add that to the block? You can't have more than one version of a plugin installed anyway

Comment: I thought it is necessary, due to xml created by jenkins when I configured this plugin via gui

Comment: It _should_ work anyway - since it looks at the type and instanciates that first. If it loads, I would just ignore that. Your plugin configuration list should contain the expected plugin version anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explicitly add the version number to the plugin declaration.  Instead, add it to the project's configuration.

Jenkins is moving in the direction of Configuration as Code with plugins such as the [JCasC plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md) making it's way into the [Jenkins core platform](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jep/tree/master/jep/201).

As seen from the documentation, you can configure other plugins through this plugin which was accepted as native Jenkins feature.